# I have a problem with displaying children pages of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, child-pages, count

All I need is to get a number of children pages of a custom post type
This is my query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'all_products',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order'
);

$child_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

There are some HTML here, and after that, when I need the number of children pages, I have this

```
<?php while ( $child_query->have_posts() ) : $child_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php
    $children = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'parent' => 0, 
    'post_type' => 'all_products' ) );
    $children_num =  count( $children );
    echo $children_num;
    ...
```

After this is executed, I only get 0
If I echo the_permalink(); I get the right link to a child page... Everything seems to be working, only this is the problem

I would appreciate any help or advice. Thanks

Comment: Looks like the_permalink(); will echo the link for a post_type' ='all_products'.

From the docs for get_pages() :
This function can also retrieve other post types using the 'post_type' parameter, but the type must be hierarchical like pages, or the function will return false.
Also looks like  the 'parent' and  'child_of' values are not well, since you are trying to get childs of a given post but hoping they are at the father level, sounds contradictory for me

Comment: Well, I originally tried without parent and post_type, but it didn't work either. But everything works fine if I add 'page' as 'post_type'. I have also added hierarchical to be true in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
So if i understand correctly what you want is

```
$children = get_posts( array( 'parent'=> get_the_ID() )); // 'post_type' => 'all_products' in option
```

Have you tried removing "parent"=>0, meaning that a page has no parent like this

```
$children = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'svi_proizvodi' ));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me :(
If it's only 'page' it works fine, but not with custom post type